# How can I stage individual lines from a deleted file in Git?

Tags: git, git-gui

I have deleted a file from my working tree by splitting it's content up and moving it into seperate files. I've done all this work at once and now I want to commit the changes as individual commits, with each commit moving one section of the big file into a new smaller file.

I.e. I have:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    big.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        small-1.txt
        small-2.txt
        small-3.txt
        small-4.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Normally when staging my changes I'd just select the hunks or lines that are relevant for that commit (using `git gui`, say, or `git add -p`). But with a deleted file when I try and do this my request is ignored – it's either the whole file or nothing.

I know that I can use `git add -N` on an untracked file to specify that it will be added, and then select individual lines from that file to add in its first commit. But running `git add -N` on a deleted file doesn't have the same effect.

So: is there a way I can stage individual lines from a deleted file, and spread that deletion over multiple commits? This is without having to go back, resurrect the file and make the deletions one-by-one, which is of course the brute-force option.

Comment: If you use a better GUI tool it can probably handle it easily. I would suggest trying git-fork

Comment: @JoePhillips I thought I'd seen them all, but I've never encountered [git-fork](https://git-fork.com/) before. Wow, it even has a UI for interactive rebase! I'll definitely be giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not have this built in, but you can achieve it trivially: just write an *empty* file into your work-tree.

```
cp /dev/null big.txt
```

or:

```
: > big.txt
```

for instance in a typical Unix/Linux shell.  You now have an empty file—zero bytes long—as your `big.txt`, and you can run `git add -p` as usual.

(This doesn't save a lot of effort since `git add -p` treats the entire deletion as one big hunk, but it might be what you wanted.)

Comment: `git gui` behaves slightly oddly when doing this on a `git rm` file – I find that if I have run `git rm` and then make an empty file, I then have to unstage the deleted version _and_ rescan in order for `git gui` to show me a diff. But this does do the job!